# How to set a class active in ul li div in html using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu items in which i have ul li elements and i want to change color etc of my li class when a navigation bar is clicked. 
I have written down some javascript for this but it only open the navigation menu item but when i click on sub items the top menu item get closed and the li item can not be set active.
here is my Javascript for this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#moduleNav .locked').tooltip();
              $('#moduleNav').on('hide', function () {
                  $(this).find('.accordion-group').each(function () {
                      $(this).removeClass('open');
                  });
              });
              $('#moduleNav').on('show', function (e) {
                  $(e.target).siblings('.accordion-group').addClass('open');
              });
              $('#moduleNav').on('show', function (e) {
                  $(e.target).siblings('.accordion-inner').addClass('li.active');
              });
          });
    </script>
```

here is html of this :

```
<div class="accordion-group  ">
 <a class="accordion-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenuitem" data-parent="#moduleNav" href="javascript:void(0);">Open menu item</a>
                </div>
<div id="submenuitem" class="accordion-body collapse ">
 <div class="accordion-inner">
<ul>
<li class="">
 <a href="#">sub item 1</a>
 </li>
<li class="">
 <a href="#">sub item 2</a>
</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

here is css :

```
#moduleNav .accordion-group .accordion-inner ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3ab553;
    padding: 10px 6px;
    position: relative;
}

    #moduleNav .accordion-group .accordion-inner ul li.active {
        background: #d6efd3;
    }

        #moduleNav .accordion-group .accordion-inner ul li.active:after {
            left: 100%;
            top: 50%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            border-left-color: #d6efd3;
            border-width: 10px;
            margin-top: -10px;
        }
```

Comment: `addClass('li.active')` should be `addClass('active')`. A demo that replicates other problems would help

Comment: Yes, what Charlie says, and where is `active` removed?

Answer (score 0):

Example

CSS:

```
.active{
  background:#00c189l;
}
.inactive{
  background:gray;
}
```

HTML:
     div id="example" class="inactive" onclick="Change();">Example /div

JAVASCRIPT:
Using Jquery:

```
function Change(){

   $('#example').removeClass("inactive");
   $('#example').addClass("active");
}
```

http://jquery.com/download/